# Warning: Mapping new ns to old ns and emulator stopping abruptly

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, schema, flutter-dependencies

After upgrading to Arctic Fox , I am getting the following errors, even though the emulator is running but sometimes stopping abruptly.
What is this error ?
How can I get rid of this ?

I am using the following as copied from `cmd` :

```
    > C:\Users\Debasis>flutter doctor Doctor summary (to see all details,
    > run flutter doctor -v): [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on
    > Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1165], locale en-IN) [√] Android
    > toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    > [√] Chrome - develop for the web [√] Android Studio [√] Connected
    > device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

The Error :

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Warning: Mapping new ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 Warning:
> Mapping new ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01 Warning:
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02
> to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns
> http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns
> http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning:
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02
> to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01 √
> Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. Installing
> build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... Debug service listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:57467/XzCZTOeqyQs=/ws Syncing files to device sdk
> gphone x86...

[image: The Issue]

[image: SDK Platforms]

[image: SDK Tools]

Comment: I have similar problem but under React Native. I loaded old project in Android Studio and when I try to gradle sync I am getting same problem as you: **Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns....** And I can't find out solution...

Answer (score 38):

I had a similar issue. Two things did the trick for me.

1. Updated the gradle version in my **gradle-wrapper.properties** file to the latest available version
2. Updated the gradle plugin version in my **/android/build.gradle** file to the latest available version

#### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

#### /android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
}
```

Give these a try and see if it works!

Comment: thanks this helped cleaning the warnings

Answer (score 4):

I have also the same problem, when I was updated android studio. i research to fix that issue,

**TODO ;**

**step 1 :** **GOTO** project Folder

### /android/build.gradle

to update a latest gradle version in dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
}
```

**step 2 :**

### /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

*here also to update a latest version of gradle*

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

**step 3:** go to terminal and run `flutter clean`

**step 4:** and run `flutter pub get`

**step 5:** and run your project using `flutter run` command

one more think but that issue fix that project only. if u know fix that issue permanently please let me know,

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, but after quick research, I managed to solve the problem.

step 1: Go to this webpage: [Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

step 2: Copy the build.gradle plugin to version
[image: see the image here]

step 3: Go to your flutter app project and open the "build.gradle" file under

> your_project>android

[image: see the image here]

step 4: In that file edit dependencies.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<step 2 copied version>'

[image: see the image here]

step 5: Now re-run your flutter app. You might see a new error, showing

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.

[image: see the image here]

Now follow the instructions given in that error. (highlighted area in the image)