# Compiler error in Flutter - .AAR .Metadata

Tags: flutter, kotlin, aar

I'm trying to compile my Flutter app but I get the following problem:

`Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.media2:media2-session:1.2.0.

When I update the compile SDK to 31, I get this message:

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
```

I have made changes to some of the gradle files and the warning messages have been removed but now the message below appears:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.media2\media2-session\1.2.0\e110e7db678fbfc107af48fe6110e3cc713f4564\media2-session-1.2.0.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/media2/session/MediaBrowser$Builder'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat$Token'
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(13937): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54956/S_ZxDICL0Ic=/ws
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
```

The Notes within the message are highlighted in red so I think this could possibly lead to the root cause/solution.

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: These are warnings that your existing codesare mapped to new versions. Did it build after these warnings?

Comment: Not quite...The build ends at the splash screen @KaushikChandru

Comment: Do you use firebase?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68959921/16606510 Hope this helps.

Comment: I use AWS, I have edited my question. @KaushikChandru

Comment: It kind of helped but I have another problem, I have edited my question with the second problem. @Maqsood

Comment: It's fine. Jetifier rewrote the library and the app built successfully. The issue is with one of your packages which is not upgraded.